# Encapsulating properties in a property/context class

Tags: java

I have created a `BicycleProducer` interface which has different implementations: `OffroadBicycleProducer`, `FastBicycleProducer` and so on.

Each of these factories requires many parameters in order to produce a bicycle. I want to encapsulate these properties in a class and pass it to the `produce` method. However, the bicycles requires different properties - some may be the same - and I wonder how to do this properly. In the interface of `BicycleProducer` I have currently a method named `produce` which takes a parameter `BicycleProducingContext` which is a interface with all the common properties. And then you have implementations that implement it and add the necassary properties based on what type of bicycle it is. And then you would need to cast it in the `produce` method....but I don't know. It seem somewhat dodgy (it might not be) I feel.

Is this is a fine approach or should I do it in another way?

```
public interface BicycleProducer {
    void produce(BicycleProducingContext context);
}

public class OffroadBicycleProducer implements BicycleProducer {

    public void produce(BicycleProducingContext context) {
        context = (OffroadBicycleProducingContext) context;
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface BicycleProducingContext {

    int numberOfBicycles();
    void brand(String brand);
}

public class OffroadBycycleProducingContext implements BicycleProducingContext {

    //..
}
```

Comment: show real code, easier to read than paragraphs

Comment: Ok, added some example code (trimmed version).

Comment: Looks like double dispatch... maybe you should adapt the *Visitor* to fit your case.

Answer (score 1):

I find two things sort of awkward about your proposed design:

1. To me, it looks like you may not need factories (i.e. your `Producer` classes) at all. Factories are useful when you need to construct an object whose type is not known at compile time. But since you're thinking of having separate factory classes for each type of bicycle (e.g. `OffroadBicycleProducer`), I assume you do know what kind of object you want to construct ahead of time.
2. Using a context class to make parameter passing less ugly is a good idea, but if you start creating separate context classes for each type of bicycle, then you end up in the awkward situation of having to know which context to construct as well as what data it requires -- which, if you have all that, you might as well just skip the intermediate step and construct the `Bicycle` right away.

If I was right in assuming that you do know what kind of object you need to construct ahead of time, then instead of using factories, I would go either with the builder pattern, or with plain old constructors. The constructor approach might look something like the following:

```
public abstract class Bicycle {
    private int year;
    private String color;

    public Bicycle(BicycleProducingContext context) {
        this.year = context.getYear();
        this.color = context.getColor();
    }
}

public class OffroadBicycle extends Bicycle {
    private String terrainType;

    public OffroadBicycle(BicycleProducingContext context) {
        super(context);
        this.terrainType = context.getTerrainType();
    }
}

public class FastBicycle extends Bicycle {
    private int maxSpeed;

    public FastBicycle(BicycleProducingContext context) {
        super(context);
        this.maxSpeed = context.getMaxSpeed();
    }
}
```

If you don't know what type of `Bicycle` you want to construct until runtime, then you can use the above approach with a single factory. For example:

```
public class BicycleFactory {
    public static Bicycle constructBicycle(BicycleProducingContext context) {
        if (context.getBicycleType().equals("OffroadBicycle")) {
            return new OffroadBicycle(context);
        } else if (context.getBicycleType().equals("FastBicycle")) {
            return new FastBicycle(context);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encountered unrecognized Bicycle type: " + context.getBicycleType());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I'm not over-simplifying your use-case, but it seems to me like the above should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: But this is a EJB service, it is in the Service layer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the service layer prevents you from being able to construct `Bicycles` this way.  Can you elaborate?